# Sending USDT in testnet -- always "out of energy"

Tags: javascript, blockchain, tron, tronweb

On my account in Shasta I have 5k TRX and the same amount of USDT. I'm trying to send USDT. So far it's failed with a result `Failed -Out of Energy`. For instance:

```
async function transferTronTRC20Token(amount, privateKey, contractAddress) {
  let url = TRON_API_URL;
  const tronWeb = new TronWeb({
    fullHost: url,
    headers: {},
    privateKey: privateKey,
  });

  const options = {
    feeLimit: 10_000_000,
    callValue: 0
  };

  const tx = await tronWeb.transactionBuilder.triggerSmartContract(
    contractAddress,
    'transfer(address,uint256)',
    options,
    [{
      type: 'address',
      value: toWallet
    }, {
      type: 'uint256',
      value: amount * 1_000_000
    }]
  );

  if (!tx.result || !tx.result.result) {
    return console.error(`triggerSmartContract: ${tx}`);
  }

  const signedTx = await tronWeb.trx.sign(tx.transaction);
  if (!signedTx.signature) {
    return console.error(`trx.sign: ${signedTx}`);
  }

  return await tronWeb.trx.sendRawTransaction(signedTx);
}
```

===>

https://shasta.tronscan.org/#/transaction/64b190a7064926a62a19c28ecef0454d50b2c38af4711093a111e845e9488664

The USDT contract I use is:

`TG3XXyExBkPp9nzdajDZsozEu4BkaSJozs`

How can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transaction failed due to your fee limit

```
...
    feeLimit: 10_000_000,  <-- 10 TRX
...
```

Tron uses energy to run smart contract transactions. If there is no energy in the account, it will then burn TRX.

You can either

1. Stake (freeze) TRX to get energy and use the energy for your smart contract transaction. You can unfreeze your TRX to get back your TRX.
2. Set higher fee limit so it can burn TRX.

Comment: 1) How many of TRX approximately would I have to stake?

Comment: It depends on the total freeze TRX in the chain.. The more TRX frozen in the chain, the less energy you get. It changes everyday, but freezing and unfreezing doesn't cost anything (you can only unfreeze your TRX after some amount of time, should be 24 hours...)